# Can local storage options such as LocalStorage, IndexedDB, and WebSQL be used for Android/IOS apps?

Tags: android, ios, local-storage, indexeddb, quasar-framework

I'm looking for a local storage option for an Android/IOS app I'm making for an offline mode. However, I'm confused on whether or not these options require the use of a browser. Reading up on LocalStorage and IndexedDB it seems like it everything is stored within a browser, however, the app I'm making is built in Quasar and does not use a browser. Can these options still be used for what I am trying to make?

Answer (score 0):

Android and iOS apps built by Quasar use Cordova which provides a WebView to run the app, so you do indeed use a browser internally.  According to the [Cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html) LocalStorage and WebSQL are available to both Android and iOS.  IndexedDB is only available to Android.

Comment: Is this answer obsolete now? There is nothing in the [docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html#indexeddb) that says indexdb doesn't work on ios.